# Strange issue with table background colours in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to get some html to work in an email (Outlook 2010), and I've come across a bizarre issue.

Note: All this testing is done in IE9, toggling between IE8 and IE9 browser mode.

In Outlook the table with the class `header` doesn't render isn't background colour, which is defined like

```css
.header {
    background-color: #161D23;
}
```

If I then choose to View in Browser, IE9 boots up and renders the email correctly, with the header background.

If whilst in IE9 mode, I open the dev tools, uncheck the background CSS rule, the colours disappears as expected, but when I check it again, it doesn't get re-applied.

If I do the above with IE9 in IE8 browser mode, the colour is re-applied.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

I'll try and mock up a demo now to demonstrate.

Comment: try to set background:#161D23; instead background-color: #161D23;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email client are notoriously annoying to work with. You should be using a [table layout](http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/html/), and defining backgrounds and other properties using both [CSS](http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/) and attributes, such as:

```
<table bgcolor="#161D23" style="background:#161D23;">
```

read more about cross client support [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) and mailchimp has a great resource [here](http://templates.mailchimp.com/) when it comes to all things email related.

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a try.